# VSTS - SQL Server Deploy Dapac Task Not Working

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I set up an SSDT SQL Server project in Visual Studio from where I can publish my database to on-premises target environment successfully. The requirement is however to use a CI/CD pipeline in VSTS to automate our build and deployment of this database project.

The initial task of creating a build which generates a dacpac as a build  artifact and then get copied to a drop folder on the on-premises build agent is also in place and successfully implemented.

The issue I am facing now is that my Release definition to perform the deployment to our target on-premises environment just won't work, even though it completes successfully with a green Deployment Status of "SUCCEEDED".

Not sure where to start as far as troubleshooting is concerned, but below is a screenshot of my settings/configuration for the SQL Server Deploy Dacpac Task which is expected to perform the release/deployment. Is there anything on here or elsewhere that I may be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What does the log say?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the **Path or path root** option of the SQLServer Deploy Dacpac task does not specify correctly.

You are using `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` for the Path or path root option, while the predefined variable `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` should only be used in build instead of release.

And you can use **`$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)`** or **`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`** for Path or path root option of the SQLServer Deploy Dacpac task.

[image]